# Java / Maven Loader Constraint Violation with Apache Kafka with org.slf4j

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, jira, classpath

i'm currently struggling with a java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation.
I'm developing a Jira Server App with the Atlassian Jira SDK that will include a Apache Kafka Producer. I added a dependency for Kafka in my pom.xml but i receive this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature. Listener: com.rse.atlassian.kafka.jira.eventlistener.MasterListener event: com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent
at com.atlassian.event.internal.SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker.invoke(SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker.java:53)...


Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:423)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:318)
```

I read that this might originate from the org.slf4j dependency being both in Kafka and Atlassian Jira, so i used  statements in my pom.xml. See the relevant part here:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

By this point i think i tried two dozen different permutations of this... but no luck so far.
Here is also my mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.jira:jira-api:jar:8.20.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.annotations:atlassian-annotations:jar:3.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.8.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.ofbiz:entityengine-share:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.ofbiz:entityengine:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- jta:jta:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.collectors:atlassian-collectors-util:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- opensymphony:webwork:jar:1.4-atlassian-30:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.html:atlassian-html-encoder:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- webwork:pell-multipart-request:jar:1.31.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core:jar:7.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-atlassian-2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.image:atlassian-image-consumer:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core-user:jar:7.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core-thumbnail:jar:7.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-jpeg:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-core:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-metadata:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-lang:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-io:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-image:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-tiff:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras:jar:3.4.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-key-manager:jar:3.4.6:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-common:jar:3.4.6:provided
[INFO] |  |        \- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-api:jar:3.4.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.velocity:atlassian-velocity:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:oscore:jar:2.2.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- osworkflow:osworkflow:jar:2.9.0-atlassian-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- opensymphony:propertyset:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.cache:atlassian-cache-api:jar:5.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.instrumentation:atlassian-instrumentation-core:jar:3.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.beehive:beehive-api:jar:4.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.tenancy:atlassian-tenancy-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.event:atlassian-event:jar:4.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.upgrade:upgrade-task-framework-api:jar:2.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.crowd:embedded-crowd-api:jar:4.3.6-743967e012:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:26.0-jre:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.fugue:fugue:jar:2.7.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- io.atlassian.fugue:fugue:jar:4.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13-atlassian-6:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13-atlassian-6:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.5-atlassian-2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.mail:atlassian-mail:jar:5.1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.threadlocal:atlassian-threadlocal:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-unshaded:jar:v20181008:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-externs:jar:v20181008:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.26:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.velocity.htmlsafe:velocity-htmlsafe:jar:3.2.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-api:jar:5.3.13:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webfragment:jar:5.3.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webfragment-api:jar:5.3.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.ozymandias:atlassian-plugin-point-safety:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.13:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource:jar:4.3.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource-spi:jar:4.3.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource-api:jar:4.3.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:4.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.sourcemap:sourcemap:jar:1.7.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource-compiler-gcc:jar:4.3.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.gadgets:atlassian-gadgets-api:jar:7.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.johnson:atlassian-johnson-core:jar:4.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-servlet:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1-atlassian-2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.profiling:atlassian-profiling:jar:3.2.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.scheduler:atlassian-scheduler-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.analytics:analytics-api:jar:6.1.12:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.application:atlassian-application-api:jar:2.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.atlassian:lucene-extras:jar:7.3.1-atlassian-4:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-javaconfig:jar:0.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.framework:jar:4.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wink:wink-client:jar:1.1.3-incubating:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wink:wink-common:jar:1.1.3-incubating:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- com.atlassian.upm:upm-api:jar:2.15:test
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2-atlassian-1:compile
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-api:jar:8.0.7:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-spi:jar:8.0.7:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-host:jar:8.0.7:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-plugin:jar:8.0.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-common:jar:8.0.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.security:atlassian-secure-xml:jar:3.2.14:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.24:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.3:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.atlassian.frontend:atlassian-frontend-runtime-plugin:jar:0.3.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.templaterenderer:atlassian-template-renderer-api:jar:4.1.5:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.servicedesk:jira-servicedesk-api:jar:4.13.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:jar:1.6.5:provided
[INFO] |  \- io.atlassian.util.concurrent:atlassian-util-concurrent:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.plugin:atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation:jar:2.2.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.sal:sal-api:jar:3.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.9-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:provided
```

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Comment: I do not know about your exact case but, when you add the dependency on org.slf4j:slf4j-api directly, you will still get the conflicting jars in your classpath. On the other hand you probably need the dependency for compiling and running in dev. So, I would keep the provided dependency to com.atlassian.jira:jira-api *without* the exclusions, *keep* the exclusions in org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients and any other place that transitively includes them and *drop the direct dependency on org.slf4j:slf4j-api*.

Comment: Remove provided scope from a dependency if you're trying to override it

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos i tried as you said. Drop the direct dependency and the exclusions in jira-api and keep the exclusions in kafka. Sadly, i still get the same error

Comment: @OneCricketeer do you mean i should delete <scope>provided</scope> from the org.slf4j at the bottom of my pom.xml, or from the jira-api dependency with the exclusions?

Comment: From the bottom. Unless the server you deploy the JAR into already has `slf4j-api-1.7.30:jar:`, then don't use `provided`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from `org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.framework`, so you should try adding that as a dependency with its own slf4j exclusion as well.

Then, try again, and repeat as needed, based on each package name that is shown in the error.

Alternatively, you could see if adding the maven-shade-plugin will help to rename the `kafka-clients` packages and not have conflicting classes.